# The Coproduct of two spaces is the same as the disjoint union and is homeomorphic to the union when the spaces are disjoint

Tags: general-topology

Let  $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces.

Consider the set $$X  \cup Y = \{ x\; |\; x \in X \text{  or  } x \in Y\}$$

In all the following I suppose that $X$ and $X$ **are disjoint**.

I want to understand the relation between the coproduct $X\sqcup Y$ which is the space of couples $(x,0)$ and $(y,1)$ and the union $X\cup Y$. Is it true that the two spaces $X\sqcup Y$ and $X\cup Y$ are homeomorphic ? I think it is true and the homeomorphism is the map $$X\cup Y \to X \sqcup Y$$ that maps $x$ to $(x,0)$ if $x\in X$ and to $(x,1)$ if $x\in Y$.  The map is clearly bijective but I don't know if is a homeomorphism and under what topology we put on both spaces this become a homeomorphism.

Is this correct and is the existence of this homeomorphism is the reason why we often call the coproduct by the disjoint union of $X$ and $Y$

Comment: This: "and under what topology we put on both spaces this become a homeomorphism" is the crux of the matter, which topologies are you using? If you take a description of the usual topologies on both spaces, it follows rather directly that the map is a homeomorphism.

Comment: One may equip $X\cup Y$ with the topology coherent with the cover by $\{X,Y\}$, that means a set is open iff its intersection with each of the sets is open in that set. When $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, this is just the topology of the disjoint union of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Concerning the topology on $X\sqcup Y$: set $U\sqcup V$ is open
in $X\sqcup Y$ iff $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$.
If the underlying sets of $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint then $X\cup Y$
can be equipped with a sortlike topology.

Comment: Please drhab what do you mean by a sortlike topology ?

Comment: $X\cup Y$ can be equipped with a topology characterized by: if $U\subseteq X$ and $V\subseteq Y$ then $U\cup V$ is open in $X\cup Y$ iff $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$.

Comment: Ok thanks alot.. so in this post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554333/is-the-disjoint-union-of-two-disjoint-subsets-always-homeomorphic-to-their-union they are able to find counterexamples by choosing to put the subspace topology on the set $X\cup Y$ instead of the one you mentioned?

Comment: In particular what topology could we put on $[0,1)\cup \{1\}=[0,1]$ that could make $[0,1)\cup \{1\}=[0,1]\cong [0,1)\sqcup \{1\}$ and if this homeomorphism exists then $[0,1]$ would be disconnected !

Comment: The topology may be the coherent one for the covering $\{[0,1),\{1\}\}$. A subset $U$ of $I$ is open iff $U\cap [0,1)$ is open in $[0,1)$ (and if $U\cap\{1\}$ is open in $\{1\}$, but this is trivially satisfied). If we use that topology, then $I\cong[0,1)\sqcup\{1\}$. Since the Euclidean topology on $I$ does not disconnect it, this example shows that a space may not have the topology coherent with some covering.